# Loading non-spatial tables from geopackage into ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, table, geopackage

I have a geopackage comprising spatial and nonsapatial tables. I would like to be able to load all of the tables into an ArcGIS Pro 2.6 project, however, when I connect to the geopackage I'm only able to load the spatial tables. Likewise, iterating through the geopackage using:

```py
gpkg = "test.gpkg"

walk = arcpy.da.Walk(gpkg)

for path, names, filenames in walk:
    for fname in filenames:
        d = arcpy.Describe(os.path.join(path, fname))
        print(fname, d.dataType)
```

returns only the spatial tables.

Is there anyway to make non-spatial tables visible within ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised the issue was due to the script being used to generate the geopackage not correctly populating the `gpkg_contents` field for non-spatial tables. With this updated the non-spatial tables now appear when a connection is made within ArcGIS Pro.

Using the `attributes` for non-spatial tables as shown here: http://www.geopackage.org/spec120/#attributes , you can update `gpkg_contents` as follows:

```
INSERT INTO gpkg_contents(table_name, data_type, identifier)
VALUES ('name', 'attributes', 'identifier');
```